# WiFi works badly with strange throughput and latency

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, router

[short error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88D8k.jpg)

[long error starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCsd0.png)

[long error lasts for more than 1 min](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fy7ks.png)

These screenshots are saved during voice meeting, with constant networking bandwidth usage of several hundreds kbps. When an error starts, throughput drops to 0 for seconds, then jumps back and forth between 0 and several Gbps. If I try to ping my LAN router `192.168.1.1` during an error, `time` is usually 3000-7000 ms instead of 1-3 ms.

The other devices under the same WiFi (such as my Android phone) seems not to have this error. I have reset network in network settings and it didn't help.

Update: According to comment and some research, I disabled 802.11n/ac on my 9560 card. The connection downgraded to 802.11g and keeps stably until now. It seems something wrong with the n protocol since it worked well under ac.

Comment: It's clearly reporting garbage numbers, since your 9560 card's max PHY rate is 1733 Mbps, so its max throughput is probably around 1.2Gbps. Also, it would have to be doing AC to get that, but the link type shows as N, which would max out at 300Mbps PHY rate, for just over 200Mbps of throughput. I don't think you can believe anything your see here. The card is feeding it bogus data.

Comment: Better replace the WIFI-adapter.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I have tried to uninstall current driver and let windows reinstall the one it prefers, not helped.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Sorry for late response. Intel drivers work well until now, thanks. If you would like to write an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Intel's latest drivers for the **wireless-AC 9650** seems to have fixed the issue. **(V-21.80.2  released 3/24/2020)**
[Downloaded  from here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29455/Windows-10-Wi-Fi-Drivers-for-Intel-Wireless-Adapters?product=99446)

For future readers: 
if the updated windows drivers do not change the unstable behavior for the wireless card, Create a bootable USB with a Linux distribution. Ubuntu 18.04 is a good choice. Load the drivers for the card from Intel's Linux support section.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html

If the card is still showing unstable behavior after testing it in Linux, it is probably damaged or defective. Look into a replacement!